# Angular pipe formatting for millions

Tags: angular, pipe

I'm working with big numbers that I'm now formatting like this

```
{{total  | number:'1.0-0'}}
```

and the outcome is 45,986,592. 
I need to format the number to just have the millions and then just one digit after, so `45.9`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can't you divide total by 1,000,000 and format that with one decimal digit?

Answer (score 6):

You can built a custom pipe if you want to reuse this logic.

As Phil suggested, you can just divide it by 1,000,000

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'million'
})
export class MillionPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {

  }
  transform(value: any, digits?: any): any {
    return this.decimalPipe.transform(value/1000000, digits)
  }

}
```

Make sure you have the decimal pipe registered in your module provider so it can be injected.

Working Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aa16so?file=app%2Fmillion.pipe.ts